# Image slideshow fading in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my code for an image slideshow which is very basic. I want to add a fading transition between all of my images. My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ultimateshow=new Array()
ultimateshow[0]=['file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-1.jpg', '', '']
ultimateshow[1]=['file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-2.jpg', '', '']
ultimateshow[2]=['file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-3.jpg', '', '']
ultimateshow[3]=['file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-4.jpg', '', '']
ultimateshow[4]=['file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-5.jpg', '', '']
ultimateshow[5]=['file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow.jpg', '', '']
var slidewidth="100%" 
var slideheight="400px" 
var slidecycles="continous" 
var randomorder="no" 
var preloadimages="yes" 
var slidebgcolor='white'
var slidedelay=4500
var ie=document.all
var dom=document.getElementById
var curcycle=0

if (preloadimages=="yes"){
for (i=0;i<ultimateshow.length;i++){
var cacheimage=new Image()
cacheimage.src=ultimateshow[i][0]
}
}

var currentslide=0

function randomize(targetarray){
ultimateshowCopy=new Array()
var the_one
var z=0
while (z<targetarray.length){
the_one=Math.floor(Math.random()*targetarray.length)
if (targetarray[the_one]!="_selected!"){
ultimateshowCopy[z]=targetarray[the_one]
targetarray[the_one]="_selected!"
z++
}
}
}

if (randomorder=="yes")
randomize(ultimateshow)
else
ultimateshowCopy=ultimateshow

function rotateimages(){
curcycle=(currentslide==0)? curcycle+1 : curcycle
ultcontainer='<center>'
if (ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][1]!="")
ultcontainer+='<a href="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][1]+'"           target="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][2]+'">'
ultcontainer+='<img src="'+ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][0]+'" border="0">'
if (ultimateshowCopy[currentslide][1]!="")
ultcontainer+='</a>'
ultcontainer+='</center>'
if (ie||dom)
crossrotateobj.innerHTML=ultcontainer
if (currentslide==ultimateshow.length-1) currentslide=0
else currentslide++
if (curcycle==parseInt(slidecycles) && currentslide==0)
return
setTimeout("rotateimages()",slidedelay)
}

if (ie||dom)
document.write('<div id="slidedom"      style="width:'+slidewidth+';height:'+slideheight+'; background-    color:'+slidebgcolor+'"></div>')

function start_slider(){
crossrotateobj=dom? document.getElementById("slidedom") :      document.all.slidedom
rotateimages()
}

if (ie||dom)
window.onload=start_slider

</script>
```

I've been trying to figure this out for some time and was wondering if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

for the fading you can simply use

```css
transition:opacity 0.5s ease;
```

and you can change the 0.5s to any time you want
Then you change the opacity of the element using javascript to 0 where you want